# validating an input not working properly (python)

Tags: python

```
serviceType = ""

while serviceType != "R" or serviceType != "P":
    serviceType = input("Service type (R/P): ").upper()
    print(serviceType)
    if serviceType != "R" or serviceType != "P":
        print("Error: Invalid Entry \n")
```

Whenever I run the code above, the output, no matter what input I put into it, is the message "Error: Invalid Entry". Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the conditions in your `if` condition is always `True`, therefore you always get the error.

Try this:

```
serviceType = ""

while serviceType != "R" and serviceType != "P":
    serviceType = input("Service type (R/P): ").upper()
    print(serviceType)
    if serviceType not in ["R", "P"]: # <- line changed
        print("Error: Invalid Entry \n")
```

Comment: or even easier, just change the condition from `or` to `and` in the `if ` statement+do the same for the `while` loop if you assume that you need to exit the loop when `serviceType` is  `"R"` or `"P"`

Comment: I don't believe this works either. It no longer prints out the error message but it also just keeps rerunning the same code over and over again

Comment: Changed code according to @Alex.Kh's suggestions.

Comment: actually wait Alex.Kh's response worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment:  Please close the question if your problem is solved.

Comment: @temp116055 glad it was helpful. I hope you got the gist of the problem. This condition was always `True` as your input will always be either `not "R"` or `not "P"`. Thus, you are validating that neither are correct at the same time, which needs `and`

Comment: just did, thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more typical structure for this kind of pattern:

```
while True:
    serviceType = input('Service type (R/P): ').upper()
    if serviceType in ('R', 'P'):
        break # serviceType is either R or P
    print('Error: Invalid entry')

print(serviceType) # use the validated serviceType here
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to build a program which takes service type from user and if the service type is not R or P, it return an invalid entry message and keep taking user input until user enter R or P.
The following code works for me.

```
serviceType = ""

while serviceType != "R" and serviceType != "P":
    serviceType = input("Service type (R/P): ").upper()
    print(serviceType)
    if serviceType != "R" and serviceType != "P":
        print("Error: Invalid Entry \n")
```